# Installing r.denoise on GRASS GIS (Windows) doesn't work

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, add-ons

I try to install the r.denoise add on for GRASS GIS on my Windows machine. If I start the installation without copying the html manual by hand, I get the errnr 2 that this manual can't be found. After copying it to the right place, it doesn't find its binary. Therefore, I created a .bat file to start the .py file.

Right now, it doesn't find the binary, but if I copy/paste the content of the .bat into GRASS console, Python doesn't find my pyproj library (although installed for my home python installation).

Is there any workaround to get this one working?

Comment: Please use the Addon manager for this: g.extension. It takes care of the steps you manually did.

Comment: Apparently this stopped with an error

Comment: That's not really a detailed error message :-)

Comment: I know, but there was no error message shown. Install seems to be okay, but in the context menus r.denoise is missing after all. So, I started to install it manually (without success). Other plugins install without error. Very strange!